# app_meetme.so asterisk

Tags: asterisk, conference

I've installed Dahdi, I followed all the steps necessary for being able to make asterisk create a conference call but there is no app_meetme.so file in my /usr/lib/asterisk/moldules folder. I've tried to search the app_meetme.so and download it and put it in asterisk but no success. Need some help.
Does anyone know from where to download app_meetme.so and how to make asterisk work with it in order to create conference calls?

Need help! Appreciate

Here is the link I've tried to use, but no success in my case: http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/SLA.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asterisk version above 1.6 you have do following:

1) install kernel-devel and dahdi-devel - skip this if you compiled dahdi from source code

2) in asterisk source directory do

```
make menuconfig
```

select app_metmee in applications

3) continue with

```
 make &make install
```

Answer (score 0):

For Asterisk v11, you most likely want ConfBridge (app_confbridge.so).

See http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90108

Quoting it:

> If you do not have any DAHDI hardware in your server, using ConfBridge will allow you remove a dependency on the DAHDI kernel modules. It is also optimized for mixing with typical VOIP channels and not mixing audio from channel banks and therefore is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In asterisk installation directory type
make menuselect
And select app_meet me or confbridge for conferencing